# Vim не видит системные буферы

Tags: linux, linux-mint, vim

Vim версии 7.4 не видит системные буферы, только "вимовский". Есть ли способ вставки из системного буфера в vim? Как сделать так, чтобы vim видел эти буферы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самостоятельно нашел ответ. Думаю будет полезен не только мне:

В общем: для работы с системным буфером нужно дополнительно установить пакет `vim-gtk` вместе с котором автоматом установится и `vim-gui-common`. После этого при копировании объекта в vim он будет копироваться в системный буфер (который работает с колесиком мыши). Но вот вставить из системного буфера не получится. Для этого в файл `.vimrc` нужно будет добавить следующую строку:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

После этого можно нормально копировать (не с помощью мыши) из вима и вставлять в него из системного буфера.